# Sierpinski's triangle set of local cut points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Could you please help me identify Sierpinski's triangle set of local cut points? I know it does not have cut points but it has local cut points.Which are they?

Thank's in advance !

Comment: What happens if you delete a point that was a vertex of one of the open triangles that are removed in the construction of the set?